# how to shift values in an array in python

Tags: arrays, numpy

xs = np.linspace(-1,1,6)# [ -1 -0.6 -0.2 0.2 0.6 1]
i want it to shift        [ -0.6 -0.2 0 0 0.2 0.6]

Comment: Can you add some of the code which you have tried? This way we can have a look and find your problem together.

Comment: def chainLength(xs,ys):
    LL = np.sqrt((xs - (xs - 1)**2) + ((ys - (ys - 1))**2))
    return np.sum(LL)

Comment: and this is notation of length of path math.sqrt(xj - x(j - 1))**2 + (yj - y(j - 1))**2  and i can't use loops onyl numpy to get the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is very vague, I am assuming that you're having a problem with the np.sqrt. Since this might create Nan values, you can exchange them for zeros. Hereby avoiding this problem.

For me, your code works.

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([ 2,  3,  1,  0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10])
ys = np.array([ 2,  3,  1,  0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10])

def chainLength(xs,ys): 


    LL = np.sqrt((xs - (xs - 1)**2) + ((ys - (ys - 1))**2)) 
    LL = np.nan_to_num(LL)
    return (np.sum(LL))

chainLength(xs, ys)
```

Comment: And can u tell me this also

Comment: i just wanted to know the stuff i edited above can u help me on that also

Comment: I do not understand the question anymore. Please stop changing the original question.